# Buefy: How to get binary contents of file uploaded with <b-upload>?

Tags: buefy

**Question**

When I add the `<b-upload>` component to a page, it looks great, I'm able to add files to it, and I'm able to get the **names** of the files. But how do I get the **file contents**?

**What I have tried**

1. The [doc for the Upload component](https://buefy.org/documentation/upload) mention `File` objects. When I
   inspect those objects in running code, I only see file metadata,
   like file size and name. I'm not seeing any binary file data.
2. I found [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/gnanavadivel/pen/mKNJzb) that looks promising, but it throws an error
   when I try to upload a file:

> Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Here is the HTML from that CodePen:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <b-field class="file">
    <b-upload v-model="files">
      <a class="button is-primary">
        <b-icon icon="upload"></b-icon>
        <span>Click to upload</span>
      </a>
    </b-upload>
    <span class="file-name" v-if="files && files.length">
      {{ files[0].name }}
    </span>
  </b-field>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
Vue.use(Buefy.default);

const example = {
  data() {
    return {
      files: []
    };
  },
  watch: {
    files: function(o, n) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.$emit("load", e.target.result);
      reader.readAsText(o[0]);  // This line throws the error.
      alert();
    }
  }
};

const app = new Vue(example);

app.$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error in [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/gnanavadivel/pen/mKNJzb) I referenced above.

This line:

```
reader.readAsText(o[0]);
```

Should be this instead:

```
reader.readAsText(o);
```

The file data will be in the variable `e.target.result`, as in the original code above.